# Why does Chrome darken colors when blending with an alpha gradient?

Tags: css, cross-browser, gradient, alpha

Suppose we have two gradients with the following conditions:

- Except for their alpha parameters, the gradients are identical.
- One gradient is directly above the other, and they are perfectly registered.
- The background gradient is fully opaque.
- The foreground gradient varies in transparency.

Is it reasonable to assume that when two such gradients are blended by the browser, the foreground gradient will not have a noticeable impact on the composite output?

To test my assertion, I devised the following [test (available as a Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/x1g93Lb8/2/) using HTML and CSS:

```
<body>
<style>
div.bg {
    width: 254px;
    height: 254px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)   0%, 
        rgba(255,   0,   0, 1.0) 100%
    );
    border: 1px solid #808080;
}
div.fg {
    height: 127px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)   0%, /* If these alpha values are identical   */
        rgba(255,   0,   0, 1.0) 100%  /* (regardless of value), the phenomenon */
    );                                 /* disappears!                           */
}
</style>
<div class=bg>
    <div class=fg></div>
</div>
</body>
```

In Firefox (F), my assertion was confirmed.  In Chrome (C), it was not.  These screenshots show the results:

(F) [image: Firefox result] (C) [image: Chrome result]

Note the presence of a seam in Chrome's output.  For Chrome, this only happens when the foreground gradient's beginning and ending alpha values are *unequal*.  When they are *equal*, Chrome produces the same output as Firefox -- regardless of the actual alpha value used!

Can you determine what is going here?  Which browser is right?  Is there a specification supporting either of these behaviors, or is the alpha blending algorithm entirely up to the browser vendors?

Comment: IE behaves the same as Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. What are the odds that two independent browsers would have the same unusual behavior? Does this implicate Firefox?

Comment: Maybe. I don't usually see IE siding with Chrome with what turns out to be the correct behavior (although it does happen sometimes). I'm not all that familiar with alpha composition and such though :(

Comment: The images you've shown are consistent with those obtained when using Inkscape and overlaying a square with a gradient with another, smaller, square with the same gradient. This furthers my opinion that the answer to: `Is it reasonable to assume that when two such gradients are blended by the browser, the foreground gradient will not have a noticeable impact on the composite output?` is **no.** Similarly, looking through two semi-opaque objects in real-life presents you with an image that represents a blending of the two - **not** just one or the other. E.g tinted car-windows.

Comment: I don't know anything about Inkscape, but I can imagine there are a number of different blending modes a renderer could possibly use. However, we still don't have a good explanation for why the result is always the same (and the seam disappears) when the foreground gradient's beginning and ending alphas are equal, and yet the output is so different when they are not.

Comment: The background-color of an element is #FFF by default. When you have a semi-opaque gradient, it is the _background-color_ that shows through, **not** the content of any underlying elements. So, since each of your elements have a background-color of white (the same colour as the left colour-stop) it looks as though the `.fg` element is letting us see the `.bg` element - it's not. I've updated the fiddle. `.bg` is opaque, has a white bg and ranges from #FFF(100%) to #F00(100%). `.fg` is 75% opaque, has a blue bg and ranges from #000(25%) to #000(100%). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/x1g93Lb8/8/